# `stringr::str_replace()` for a list or replacements--but only return one output

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, stringr

I have some data in `chr` format that looks like this (it is a multi-line `chr` variable):

```
#> cyl      10
#> disp     20
```

[Code for entering the data at the end of the question]

I would like to replace the variable names (eg `cyl`, `disp`) with fuller descriptions:

```
var_labels <- list(
                  cyl =  "Number of Cylinders",
                  disp = "Displacement")
```

My desired output would be:

```
#> Number of Cylinders      10
#> Displacement     20
```

What's the easiest way to do this in the tidyverse?

I've tried using `purrr::map2()` and `stringr::str_replace()`, to iterate through all of the variables and their names, but I haven't quite gotten this right. I think part of my problem is that I don't want many list items to result from the `map2()`, I want `map2()` to keep iterating on the same output then return only one result after all of the `str_replace()` have been made.

Or perhaps there's an easier, completely different way to accomplish the whole thing?

My attempt is:

```
label_vars <- function(var, var_name){
  str_replace(output, var, var_name)
}

map2(names(var_labels), var_labels, label_vars)
```

which returns a new output for each `str_replace()`, whereas I just want one output with all replacements made:

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "Number of Cylinders      10\ndisp     20"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "cyl      10\nDisplacement     20"
```

Code for entering in the data:

```
output <-"cyl      10
disp     20"
cat(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a named vector instead of named list :

```
var_labels <- c(cyl =  "Number of Cylinders", disp = "Displacement")
```

Also you don't need `map` here since `str_replace_all` is vectorized :

```
cat(stringr::str_replace_all(output, var_labels))

#Number of Cylinders      10
#Displacement     20
```